# Getting 401 and 403 with Google Proximity API

Tags: google-beacon-platform

I've set up a project for the beacon API from google, but every request I tried keeps getting a 401 (using a public key) or a 403 with the sample app [enter link description here](https://github.com/google/beacon-platform/tree/master/samples/android)

The response says:

{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Project has not enabled the API. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.Help",
        "links": [
          {
            "description": "Google developer console API activation",
            "url": "https://console.developers.google.com/project/608941808256/apiui/api"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}

but I already enabled the API.

Comment: Did you follow the instructions for registering the app? It's a bit … involved and requires following a few steps.  What API methods are you trying to call and what are the parameters? And are you 100% sure you really enabled the Proximity Beacon API in the API console, and not accidentally the Proximity Pairing API?

Comment: @MarcWan I followed the instruction to the dot. I tried the GET method with the beacons.

Comment: I added my SHA and Bundle ID and I'm having the same problem. Are there other steps? The instructions are either very poorly documented, or I just haven't seen the instructions.

Comment: You must both register for an API key and an OAuth 2.0 client ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create an API-Key and a OAuthClient-ID [getting-started](https://developers.google.com/beacons/proximity/get-started) and link them to you app. After creating those you have to restriced them to Android only and insert the package name `com.google.sample.beaconservice` for this expamle app. Further you need to insert the sha1-key. You can use the debug key generated by the command:
`keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -list -v`

An OAuthClient-Id will be enough for this sample app. Since it does not use the `getforobserved` Method, which would require the API-Key in the manifest.xml